# Ruby DBI - How to check if a recordset is empty

Tags: ruby, dbi

Using Ruby DBI, how can I check if a record set is empty? (without iterating through it or doing a count query)

```
sth = dbh.prepare("select * from things WHERE created_at > '#{start}'")
sth.execute
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always just ask the result object:

```
res = sth.execute
res.num_rows
```

The operation will have to pull down all matching records, though, so if you only need a count, you might want to select that directly.

Also **escape your SQL**. You cannot just put arbitrary strings in there. This is better:

```
sth = dbh.prepare("select * from things WHERE created_at > '%s'" % sth.escape_string(start))
```